# /var/www/ Security

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php, security

I'm running Ubuntu 16.

I have a public facing site, set up at /var/www/html/

There's some CMS software running, installed at /var/www/html/cms

The config files can be stored outside of web root for added security, so I have moved them to /var/www/config/

However, the CMS requires /var/www/config/ to have 777 permissions as it needs to write to it. (well, I think this is partly due to my user config ubuntu vs www-data, but 777 is the only permission which works).

The virtualhost setup has the DocumentRoot as /var/www/html/

In apache2.conf, I have:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
</Directory>
```

Now, my question... is this as secure as I think? I'm happy having the cms config files outside of DocumentRoot, BUT have had to give it 777 permissions and apache.conf does grant permissions to /var/www (even though there is not a virtualHost config pointing that low.

Should I be:

a) looking at fixing permissions/groups so the cms can run with 755 (or 775) permissions on the /var/www/config directory?
b) amend the apache2.conf so it doesn't grant to /var/www/html (but rather just to /var/www/html)?
c) happy and leave it as is?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

By adding www-data to the ubuntu group:

```
usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu
```

I can then change the permissions of /var/www/config/ to 755 and the cms is happy with those permissions.

However I am not sure I want www-user to have the same permissions as the ubuntu user...

As a further note, the files and folders are all owned by ubuntu because this is the user (only user) who has SFTP access to deploy files. If I amended ownership to www-data, everytime something new is deployed, it'd revert back to ubuntu ownership.

Comment: This may be a good question for https://security.stackexchange.com if you don't get a good response here on askubuntu. Use your existing stackexchange account to logon at https://security.stackexchange.com and then select to add the site to your profile.